# Performance Monitor -> ASP.NET Apps does not show web applications

Tags: windows-server-2008, asp.net, performance-monitoring

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server with several web applications installed on IIS.

I opened `Performance Monitor`, expanded `ASP.NET Apps` group, selected any of the counter, but none of my web applications show in any of the counter.

Anybody knows what might be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking under the correct Asp.Net Apps version that matches your application pool? Is there a w3wp.exe process running? Is your website stopped?

Comment: Good point, the app pool matches with the .net version number. However I don't see the w2wp.exe in memory.